Why is my VkPipeline returning null even with all other values being good?
The code:
VkPipelineLayoutCreateInfo pipelineLayoutCreateInfo{ VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_LAYOUT_CREATE_INFO };
pipelineLayoutCreateInfo.pushConstantRangeCount = 1;
pipelineLayoutCreateInfo.pPushConstantRanges = &pushConstant;

// Descriptor sets: one specific to ray tracing, and one shared with the rasterization pipeline
std::vector<VkDescriptorSetLayout> rtDescSetLayouts = { descriptorSetLayout, descriptorSetLayout };
pipelineLayoutCreateInfo.setLayoutCount = static_cast<unsigned int>(rtDescSetLayouts.size());
pipelineLayoutCreateInfo.pSetLayouts = rtDescSetLayouts.data();

vkCreatePipelineLayout(device, &pipelineLayoutCreateInfo, nullptr, &pipelineLayout);

// Create Vulkan ray tracing pipeline create info structure
VkRayTracingPipelineCreateInfoKHR rayTracingPipelineCreateInfo = {};
rayTracingPipelineCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RAY_TRACING_PIPELINE_CREATE_INFO_KHR;
rayTracingPipelineCreateInfo.stageCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(shaderStages.size()); // Assuming you have shader stages
rayTracingPipelineCreateInfo.pStages = shaderStages.data(); // Shader stages information
rayTracingPipelineCreateInfo.groupCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(shaderGroups.size()); // Number of ray tracing shader groups
rayTracingPipelineCreateInfo.pGroups = shaderGroups.data(); // Pointer to ray tracing shader groups
rayTracingPipelineCreateInfo.maxPipelineRayRecursionDepth = 1;
rayTracingPipelineCreateInfo.layout = pipelineLayout;

// Create Vulkan ray tracing pipeline
vkCreateRayTracingPipelinesKHR(device, nullptr, nullptr, 1, & rayTracingPipelineCreateInfo, nullptr, & pipeline);

The error:
The Error I'm recieving. All other values besides the pipeline are good values
I don't know why pipeline is always returning null.
I've tried moving where the pipeline was created.
And I've added the extensions I assume I need:
const char* deviceExtension[] =
{
    //Raytracing Extensions
    VK_KHR_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_EXTENSION_NAME,
    VK_KHR_SWAPCHAIN_EXTENSION_NAME,
    VK_KHR_MAINTENANCE3_EXTENSION_NAME,
    VK_KHR_RAY_TRACING_PIPELINE_EXTENSION_NAME,
    VK_KHR_BUFFER_DEVICE_ADDRESS_EXTENSION_NAME,
    VK_KHR_DEFERRED_HOST_OPERATIONS_EXTENSION_NAME,
    VK_EXT_DESCRIPTOR_INDEXING_EXTENSION_NAME,
    VK_KHR_SPIRV_1_4_EXTENSION_NAME,
    VK_KHR_SHADER_FLOAT_CONTROLS_EXTENSION_NAME
};

Hopefully someone can help
Return value:
The return value
VUID Errors:
VUID-VkRayTracingPipelineCreateInfoKHR-layout-07990(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: 1919170136 - Validation Error: [ VUID-VkRayTracingPipelineCreateInfoKHR-layout-07990 ] Object 0: handle = 0x535b660000000043, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_SHADER_MODULE; Object 1: handle = 0x612f93000000004e, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_PIPELINE_LAYOUT; | MessageID = 0x72643658 | vkCreateRayTracingPipelinesKHR(): pCreateInfos[0].pStages[0] SPIR-V (VK_SHADER_STAGE_RAYGEN_BIT_KHR) uses descriptor slot [Set 1 Binding 0] of type VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_ACCELERATION_STRUCTURE_KHR but expected VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER or VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_DYNAMIC or VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_INLINE_UNIFORM_BLOCK. The Vulkan spec states: If a resource variables is declared in a shader, and the descriptor type is not VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_MUTABLE_EXT, a descriptor slot in layout must match the descriptor type (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.275.0/windows/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkRayTracingPipelineCreateInfoKHR-layout-07990)
Objects: 2
[0] 0x535b660000000043, type: 15, name: NULL
1 0x612f93000000004e, type: 17, name: NULL

Have you tried enabling the vulkan validation layers or checking the result of vkCreateRayTracingPipelinesKHR?

I've added the vuid errors and the return value

Looks like shaderStages is wrong. Please show a [mre]. Please don't post images of error messages or return values, post the text instead

So shaderStages is called and init in this function

Error message = Your SPIR-V expects descriptor Set 1 Binding 0 to be an acceleration structure, but the descriptor set layout you've provided has a layout where Set 1 Binding 0 is a uniform buffer.
